# Are the electrons spin and his magnetic dipole moment unambiguously connected?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

Is the angle between the spin orientation and the magnetic dipole orientation for all electrons and under all circumstances the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle is the same as long as you consider a free electron. Then they are parallel:

$\vec{\mu}_\mathrm{elec}=-g_\mathrm{elec}\mu_\mathrm{Bohr}\frac{\vec{S}}{\hbar}$

with $g_\mathrm{elec}\approx 2$ (neclecting effects from quantum electro dynamics).

But when dealing with bound electrons (e.g. in an atom), where the electron also has some orbital angular momentum $\vec{l}$ things get more complicated and you have to consider the different contributions (weighting with [g-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land%C3%A9_g-factor)) of the different angular momenta (including the spin).

Comment: This is how I expected it. Have I to ask about the free electrons in a wire under the influence of an electric current in a separate question?

Comment: Could you answer [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174670/how-to-repeat-the-biot-savart-experiment-for-the-direct-current-in-a-straight-wi) question about side effects of the Biot-Savart experiment too, please?